# onDraw and invalidate method

Tags: android

I'm doing a school project. In this project I have to do a program that have one or more ball bouncing in the screen. I did some research on google to help me in this, and I found this code :

```
public class BouncingBallInside extends View {
private List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<>();

public BouncingBallInside(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}
public BouncingBallInside(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}
private void init(){
    //Add a new ball to the view
    balls.add(new Ball(50,50,100, Color.RED));
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //Draw the balls
    for(Ball ball : balls){
        //Move first
        ball.move(canvas);
        //Draw them
        canvas.drawOval(ball.oval,ball.paint);
    }
    invalidate(); // See note
} 
}
```

The ball class :

```
public class Ball{

public int x,y,size;
public int velX = 10;
public int velY=7;
public Paint paint;
public RectF oval;

public Ball(int x, int y, int size, int color){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
    this.paint = new Paint();
    this.paint.setColor(color);
}

public void move(Canvas canvas) {
    this.x += velX;
    this.y += velY;
    this.oval = new RectF(x-size/2,y-size/2,x+size/2,y+size/2);

    //Do we need to bounce next time?
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    this.oval.roundOut(bounds); ///store our int bounds

    //This is what you're looking for ▼
    if(!canvas.getClipBounds().contains(bounds)){
        if(this.x-size<0 || this.x+size > canvas.getWidth()){
           velX=-velX;
        }
        if(this.y-size<0 || this.y+size > canvas.getHeight()){
            velY=-velY;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The program works perfecly.
I studied it deeply as good as I could. But after it and after watching the documentation I couldn't understand two thing:

1. Where and when the method onDraw(Canvas canvas) is called the first time.
2. Why at the end of onDraw there is invalidate()?

I mean the documentation said :

> Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible, onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the future.

so... if this method is used to call onDraw,why don't call it direcly? what's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)The onDraw method will be called by the framework, whenever the view is invalid.  A view is invalid when it first comes on screen, so when you set your content view for an activity they layout and all views in it will be measured, laid out, then drawn (via onDraw).

After that the UI thread will call onDraw if needed every 16ms or so (so it draws at 60 FPS).

2)Its marking the view as needing to be redrawn, so the next time the the screen is drawn onDraw will be called.  Otherwise it would be skipped, as we could assume it isn't needed.

Why you don't call onDraw directly- efficiency.  In a very simple drawing system you would-  but drawing is time consuming, you don't want to do it more than you have to.  So instead of drawing immediately (which wouldn't work anyway, you wouldn't have the right Canvas to pass to onDraw), you call invalidate and the system will call onDraw if needed at a regular interval.

Note that this isn't particularly good code.  In particular, having the onDraw trigger the move which updates the balls location instead of using a timer is icky.  Having onDraw call invalidate as a result is also kind of icky.  A better solution would be to separate the view, model, and timer into more of an MVC or MVP system.